# Running macro with solver incomplete closing of excel via python

Tags: python, vba, excel, solver

I use a python program with win32com.client which opens a .xlsm file, runs a macro and closes the .xlsm file.

1. If the macro runs the solver Add-in, python closes the workbook but can not closes all Excel instances, i.e. at the end I see Excel.exe in the Task Manager.
2. If the macro manipulates cells without solver Add-in, python can Close all Excel instances.

Therefore I think it is a problem with the referenced solver.xlam in the macro.

The solver part of the macro is:

```
SolverReset SolverOk SetCell:="$A$4", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$A$1:$A$3", _
Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear" SolverOptions MaxTime:=0, Iterations:=80, Precision:=0.00001, Convergence:= _
0.0000001, StepThru:=False, Scaling:=True, AssumeNonNeg:=True, Derivatives:=1 solver_output = SolverSolve(userFinish:=True)
```

The python command is:  `xl.Quit()  del xl`

Is there any explanation for the different behaviour and what can I do for closing all Excel instances in python?